# AngularJS y ng-checked

Tags: angularjs

a ver si pueden decirme porque sucede esto.
La cosa es que tengo un doble ng-repeat donde se recorren dos listas. La primera lista es una lista de contratistas y dentro de esta lista hay otra lista de documentos. Es decir, los contratistas tienen una lista de documentos asociados a ellos.

Para recorrer las dos listas dentro del HTML tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
          <accordion close-others="true" ng-repeat="contratista in listaContratistas track by $index | filter:{activo:'S'}">
                <accordion-group heading="{{contratista.razonSocial}}">
                    <button ng-click="delContratista($index);" class="btn btn-block btn-danger btn-xs">Eliminar Contratista</button>
                    <p>Documentos obligatorios:</p>
                    <div ng-repeat="documento in contratista.documentosProyecto track by $index">
                        <div class="checkbox" ng-click="$parent.delDocumentoContratista($parent.$index, $index);" >
                        <!--<div class="checkbox" ng-click="$documento.obligatorio == 'S'? documento.obligatorio = 'N' : documento.obligatorio = 'S'" >-->
                            <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="listaContratistas[$parent.$index].documentosProyecto[$index].obligatorio == 'S'">
                                <!--<input type="checkbox" ng-checked="documento.obligatorio == 'S'">-->
                                {{documento.tipo}}
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </accordion-group>
        </accordion>
```

Los documentos que tienen los contratistas tienen una propiedad llamada obligatorio, la cual por defecto es igual a 'S'.

El problema es, que cuando se hace click en un check de cualquier contratista, se desmarca su check y el de todos los contratistas. El codigo en el controlador es el siguiente:

```
$scope.delDocumentoContratista = function(indexContratista, indexDocument){
            if($scope.listaContratistas[indexContratista].documentosProyecto[indexDocument].obligatorio == 'S'){
                $scope.listaContratistas[indexContratista].documentosProyecto[indexDocument].obligatorio = 'N';
            }else{
                $scope.listaContratistas[indexContratista].documentosProyecto[indexDocument].obligatorio = 'S';
            }
        }
```

He probado ya infinidad de cosas y sigue sin funcionar. Que tengo mal en el codigo para que me suceda esto?

Un saludo y muchas gracias.

Comment: Cual es el funcionamiento de lo que ocurre en el ng-checked? Que hace la funcion?

Comment: El problema es, que cuando deselecciono un check de un contratista lo hace en todos los check. Cuando solo deberia de hacerlo en uno.

Comment: Eso ocurre porque tus checkbox no se diferencian entre ellos, son todos iguales, llamas a la misma funcion y haces el mismo procedimiento

Comment: Y que debo de hacer para diferenciar los checkbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu tienes los datos `contratista.documentosProyecto` me imagino que estos datos tienen una `id` o algun campo que los diferencia de los demas. Debes hacer lo siguiente :

En tu controlador crea un arreglo vació, por ejemplo

`$scope.contratistaModel = [];`

Luego recorre tus datos

```
angular.forEach($scope.contratista.documentosProyecto, function(documento,index){
      $scope.contratistaModel[documento.id] = false;
})
```

Con esto conseguiras crear un arreglo, con los indices correspondientes a cada `documento.id`, se inicializa en false porque es un `checkbox` SI ES QUE FUERA EL CASO y dependiera de un valor si el `checkbox` aparece marcado o desmarcado, debes hacer tu esa validación, por ejemplo :

```
angular.forEach($scope.contratista.documentosProyecto, function(documento,index){
      if(documento..obligatorio == 'S'){
          $scope.contratistaModel[documento.id] = false;
      }else{
          $scope.contratistaModel[documento.id] = true;
      }
})
```

Luego en tu vista simplemente :

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="contratistaModel[documento.id]" ng-checked="listaContratistas(documento)">
```

Aqui ya no envias el valor que tenga, si no el objeto del `ng-repeat` completo y llamas a la funcion `listaContratistas(documento)`, en esta funcion deberias hacer esto :

```
$scope.listaContratistas = function(documento){  
    if($scope.contratistaModel[documento.id]){

    }else{

    }
}
```

Aqui evaluas si tu modelo UNICO `$scope.contratistaModel[documento.id]` esta checkeado o no, si dan check en el ya sabes que hacer.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda. Me has ayudado a comprender lo que realmente ocurria. El problema era que estaba pasando a la función el objeto que venia de una asignación por referencia. Ahora en vez de asignarlos por referencia clono el objeto. No lo he realizado exactamente como me has comentado pero me has ayudado muchisimo. Muchas gracias!!!

Comment: mucha suerte @EnriqueRodrigo y cualquier cosa acude a la comunidad :D